# Is twitter still on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Is twitter still on Rails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this link - http://highscalability.com/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster. It seems that they moved from Ruby to Java based stack. Here you will find more details on the current twitter architecture - http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/06/Twitter-Architecture.

Comment: They moved a small part from C to Scala. In particular, they augmented their MySQL database with an in-house Message Queue written in Scala. Most of the stuff that used to be RoR is still RoR.